# Is there a way to continiously run some Javascript code in a minimized browser app on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I would like to continously run some web requests using the Fetch API in the background (e.g. one request every second), even when the browser app is minimized on iOS.

I've tried all Web Worker types (Worker, ServiceWorker, SharedWorker), but they all seem to stop operating a few seconds after the browser app is minimzed. The Periodic Sync API seems to be exactly what I need but it is not available on iOS.

Comment: Thankfully, for battery life, the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to execute a function every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, `setInterval()` (which I assume you meant) also stops working when the app is minimized.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I did not know that, thanks for telling me.